# How to make a discord.py command be able to execute a ctx.send command

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

Right now, I have a bot that I want to be able to control with Python commands. Here is my code for the >execute command, which I want to use to execute Python snippets.

````
async def execute(ctx, *, arg):
    if ctx.author.id == 645264167623983124:
        try:
            exec(arg.replace("```", ""))
            await ctx.send(embed=msg(title="Execution complete!", desc="The code ran successfully."))
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(embed=msg(title="Error", desc=str(e)))
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed=msg(title="Nuh Uh Uhh", desc="You are not allowed to use this command!"))
````

However, I also want to use this command to send test messages, like this:

```
>execute await ctx.send("Hello world!")
```

When I run this, it says:

```
Error
'await' outside function (<string>, line 1)
```

But when I run it without the await, it says it ran fine, but my console where the bot is running says this:

```
<string>:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: did you use the `@client.command()` decorator?

Comment: Yes I did. Looks like I didn't include it, whoops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work using [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) instead for the async functions:

````
arg = arg.replace("```", "")
if arg.startswith("await"):
    await eval(arg.replace("await ", ""))
else:
    exec(arg)
````